# Regex that matches begining of number anywhere in line

Tags: php, regex

I have one problem, I need regex that matches (number phones), any number that starts with 06 or 6 and its equal or longer than 7 characters and it needs to be matched anywhere in sentence.

So far I've got this:

```
(^(06|6).+.{5})
```

and it matches me most of what I need, example:

```
065 123 456,   
065123456,
65123456
```

and etc etc, my problem is that I need also to match it even if there is text before the number ex: test 065123456 (or any of those cases that i already wrote).

Summary: The problem is that i dont know how to match words(or anything before number that starts with 06 or 6) and then number that starts with 06 or with 6.

Comment: Just... don't `^`anchor it?

Comment: But I don't need to match 12306123 , only the number that starts with 06 or 6, not anywhere in that number

Comment: `(?<!\d)` ensures there is no digit before.

Comment: It won't match, there is not 5 digits after?

Comment: You could use a word boundary `\b` instead of the anchor `^` to make sure it's not matching mid-word or mid-number

Comment: put star(yourregex)star ;)  which means any match in the string. ^ this is the begining of the line, not begin with, you should use white space identifier like these   [ \t\r\n\v\f] if you want to match the strings at the middle of the string.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for that, it worked with \b instead of anchor ^, gonna try with stars also, need to get more into regexes asap, Thanks for help guys! :)

Comment: @user2102266 thats not quite working :) but \b solves it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the caret symbol (`^`) in your pattern. The pattern can be simplified to:

```
(0?6\d{6})
```

Comment: But I don't need to match 12306123

Comment: @Pitchwaiz You can use `\b` or `\D` before the opening parenthesis. `\D(0?6\d{6})` or `\b(0?6\d{6})` both would work.

Comment: yep thats working also, \b and \D , so usefull . thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A lookbehind can assert that there is no number before the `06`:

```
((?<!\d)0?6 rest of regex here)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will match a number that begins with 0 or 06 followed by at least 6 other numbers or spaces:

```
((?<!\d)0?6[\d| ]{6,})
```

I'm not sure how to match at least 6 *numbers* interspersed with any number of spaces off the top of my head, though…

Comment: This could work, gonna try it also, thanks for help! :)